# P4 Triggers - edit changelist description after submit on client

Tags: perforce

If I submit the changelist in P4V, I'd like to change the description of the changelist through the P4 trigger.

like this,

[image]

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/scripting.triggers.push.html
Command executed with change-submit(or change-commit) trigger but Description did not change.

```
p4 --field Description=DESCRIPTIONS... change -o CHANGELISTNUM | p4 change -i -u
```

I've tried p4 change options -i -u and -i -f, all option not working on trigger command.(script)
(In the environment where the trigger works, the -f option is possible because the superuser account is logged in.)

Has anyone changed the description through the trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; it should work if you use `-f`.  `-u` won't work unless the trigger is running as the user who owns the changelist (i.e. the user who's doing the submit), but `-f` will work as long as the trigger is running as an admin.  If it's not working, double check your permissions.

Simple example:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 triggers -o
(...snip...)
Triggers:
        update-desc change-commit //... "cmd /c p4 --field Description+=DESCRIPTIONS... change -o %change% | p4 change -if"

C:\Perforce\test>p4 submit -d "test description"
Submitting change 301.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //stream/main/foo#6
Change 301 submitted.
Change 301 updated.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 change -o 301
(...snip...)
Description:
        test description
        DESCRIPTIONS...
```

Triggers don't execute in a command shell, so if you want to use shell features like `|` redirection, you may need to explicitly use a command shell to process the command line (in my case `cmd /c` does that job).

Note the extra `Change 301 updated` in the submit output; that's the output of the trigger's `p4 change -i` being echoed back to the client.  If your trigger isn't working, look carefully at the output that you're getting from the `p4 submit`, since it will probably contain an error message that gives you a clue where the trigger is failing.  If you see the entire change spec being echoed back to you, that's a clue that the redirection isn't working.  (If you can't find any trigger output in P4V, go do a test submit from the CLI; if you still can't find any, double check the triggers entry for typos, and the server log for errors.)

Note that `change-submit` is a *pre-submit* trigger, whereas `change-commit` is a *post-submit* trigger.  If you want the trigger to fire after a successful submit, you want `change-commit`.